# minecraft summon item with custom name 1.14

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I'm making something for my friends and I've been trying to find a summon item generator with a custom name and I have found one but the custom name does not work. `/summon item -137 28 -204 {Item:{id:black_terracotta,Count:1,tag:{display:{Name:"Dark Matter"}}}}`

Answer (score 2):

The `Name` tag expects a string in JSON format, this is the correct command:

```
/summon item -137 28 -204 {Item:{id:black_terracotta,Count:1,tag:{display:{Name:'{"text":"Dark Matter"}'}}}}
```

Comment: @abey Welcome to StackExchange! If this answer solved your problem, consider accepting it, this is beneficial to both you and the answerer: https://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem is that you've just used `item`. The command should be `minecraft:item`.

Here is the example of it.

```
/summon minecraft:item -137 28 -204 {Item:{id:black_terracotta,Count:1,tag:{display:{Name:"Dark Matter"}}}}
```